# bash command substituation comes up blank

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I have the following `Dockerfile`

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/docker/library/python:3.7-slim-buster as base
WORKDIR /code
RUN apt-get update -y && \
    pip install --upgrade pip && \
    mkdir ~/.aws \
    && touch ~/.aws/credentials
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs npm awscli jq
```

Which is base from slim-buster.
I am trying to do a one command `aws sts`command from this recommended [AWS sts assume role in one command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63241009/aws-sts-assume-role-in-one-command) solution

However the the eval solution is coming up "blank" or the parenthesis is not escaped properly within a make command:

```
sts-qa:
    eval $(aws sts assume-role --role-arn arn:aws:iam::1234556778:role/aws-role --role-session-name pebble | jq -r '.Credentials | "export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=\(.AccessKeyId)\n export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=\(.SecretAccessKey)\nexport AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=\(.SessionToken)\n"')
```

the error I get is:

```
root@b79fd0ebf8cf:/code# make sts-qa
eval \n export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=\(.SecretAccessKey)\n export AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=\(.SessionToken)\n"')
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: ")" unexpected
```

I have tried:

- escaping all () from the command. i get the following error: `/bin/sh: 2: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string`
- assigning the content of the
  $(...) into a variable. what I get back as an output is `eval` (the
  entire bash command is blank

I have ran out of ideas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(...)` is Makefile syntax for expanding a variable name, so the `(` is closed by the first unescaped `)` in the command you want to execute. You need to double the `$` to have it be treated literally.

```
sts-qa:
        eval $$(aws sts assume-role --role-arn arn:aws:iam::1234556778:role/aws-role --role-session-name pebble | jq -r '.Credentials | "export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=\(.AccessKeyId)\n export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=\(.SecretAccessKey)\nexport AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=\(.SessionToken)\n"')
```

Comment: Functional, and thanks for the explanation between Makefile and the actual command.